# Как настроить репозиторий в гите, чтобы мержить можно было только после трех апрувов?

Tags: github

Как настроить репозиторий в гите, чтобы мержить можно было только после трех апрувов?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

В настройках репозитория (Setting) раздел Branches, напротив "Branch protecting rules" (правила защиты веток) жмете "Add rule" (добавить правило), пишите название ветки, для которой задаете правило (например, master), ставите галку "Require pull request reviews before merging" (требовать ревью перед слиянием пулл-реквеста), в комбо ниже выбираете количество ревью перед слиянием, в самом низу жмете кнопку "Create" (создать правило):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Документация: [Managing a branch protection rule](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/managing-a-branch-protection-rule)